# Solve $5\sin z - 7 \cos z = 8$ for complex $z$

Tags: complex-analysis

Solve $5\sin z - 7 \cos z = 8$ for complex $z$. What I did is that I plugged $-i\sinh iz$ for $\sin z$ and $\cosh iz$ for $\cos z$. Then I turned everything into a single fraction leaving $0$ on the right side of the equation, finally turned the problem to a problem of finding when the numerator is $0$, simplified to a quadratic equation of the form $(7-5i) e^{2iz} + 6 e^{iz} - (7 - 5i) = 0$. The problem is that solving this equation is really inconvenient, the numbers in it are going to be too big and I'd need to find a complex root. How else can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have $5\sin z-7\cos z=8$ iff
$$5\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}-7\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}=8$$
which is true iff
$$(5-7i)e^{iz}-(5+7i)e^{-iz}=16i.$$
By setting $t=e^{iz}$, you need to solve
$$(5-7i)t^2-16it-(5+7i)=0.$$
This last equation has positive $\Delta$, so you can quickly find your two answers for $t$, let's note them $t_1$ and $t_2$.

Then, you need to check for which $z$ you have $e^{iz}=t_1$ and $e^{iz}=t_2$ by regarding both real and imaginary parts or by putting $t_1$ and $t_2$ in their trigonometric form.